# Remove extra leading spaces in single-line comments in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, comments, indentation

My projects in Eclipse using *spaces* to format code, *not tabs*. When commenting lines with single-line comment (pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>), leading spaces just shifts to right, breaking adjustment with other non-commented lines, for example:

```
class Sample
{
    public int x;
//    public int y;
}
```

What I want is:

```
class Sample
{
    public int x;
//  public int y;
}
```

Manually removing spaces is tedious. Is there any solution for this? (plugin, some kind of macro, any other?)

I don't want to use tab-formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem . I found workaround for it .

1. press ctrl+F
2. check Regular expressions option
3. In find box put  **//\s+** and in replace box put **//**
4. Do Find Replace or Replace all
5. Now if you want your code to be aligned just do select all (ctrl+A) then press ctrl+I