# Indenting single line comment code add spaces in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I indent a single line commented code using ctrl + 'i' in Eclipse it adds extra space and throws that line out of alignment.
Is there a way where I can indent a single line comment without adding spaces to it.

**Before Indentation:**

```
public class Test
{
//  public static String str; 
    public static String str1;
}
```

**After Indentation:**

```
public class Test
{
    //  public static String str; 
    public static String str1;
}
```

Please note:

1. Only reference to my issue I could find was this question asked 2 years back but the answer is not satisfactory. Link:
   [Remove extra leading spaces in single-line comments in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870271/remove-extra-leading-spaces-in-single-line-comments-in-eclipse)
2. [Screenshot of the issue for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6NZK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check yout toe [Formatter](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-formatter.htm) options and adjust intends to your needs

Alternatively you can use `//@formatter:off` and  `//@formatter:on` to disable formatting for lines between these 2 tags.